# Create dictionary using split() operation and list comprehension

Tags: python, split, list-comprehension

I want to create 'dictionary' using `list comprehension':

```
a_list = ['1, Lastoŭski', '2, Kupala', '3, Kolas']
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
d = {key: value for (key, value) in s.split(',') for s in a}

>>> NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

But this is completely wrong. Could you help me?

Comment: `dict(s.split(', ') for s in a_list)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as pointed out by @Delgan, it can be done directly via

```
d1 = dict(keyval.split(", ") for keyval in a_list)
```

without the inner nesting :)

older approach which were not really correct :-

```
d = [a.split(',') for a in a_list]
d1 = {key: val for key,val in d}
```

or

```
d1 = {key: val for key,val in (a.split(',') for a in a_list)}
```

Comment: Can't understand the downvote.. do comment if downvoting.

Comment: You do not need a nested list / dict comprehension to solve the problem.

Comment: @Delgan got it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

No need for a dictionary comprehension. You're making something more complex than it needs to be ;).

```
a_list = ['1, Lastoŭski', '2, Kupala', '3, Kolas']
d = {}
for i in a_list:
    temp = i.split(', ')
    d[temp[0]] = temp[1]

print d
# returns: {'3': 'Kolas', '2': 'Kupala', '1': 'Lastoŭski'}
```

If you need a list comprehension, then this will suffice:

```
d = dict((key, value) for key, value in [i.split(', ') for i in a_list])
```

You were close, but you were missing brackets

Comment: Thanks, but I am studding `functional` opportunities of `Python` and want to do it with `comprehension`

Comment: You are actually making it more complex that it needs to be. ^^' `d = dict(keyval.split(", ") for keyval in a_list)` works just fine.

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ Edited

Comment: @Delgan Hey learn something new every day :). I still don't see why my answer is downvoted - it's still correct

Comment: Indeed, it is correct, but it is not the correct way to do it. So OP will learn something inaccurate.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 d = dict(map(str, x.split(',')) for x in a_list)
```

This would help.

Comment: There is no need to call `map`. :)

Comment: Why downvote? If you are downvoting please point out why?

Comment: Why not if it makes a dictionary out of the list?

Comment: The result of `str.split()` is already a "list" of string, so casting it to `str` once again makes no sense.